# Different Bundle Id and Package ID in Parse push notifications

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am working on an app that uses the Parse push notifications. This app has a two word name. I have Android version and the iOS version. I have set the bundle id to **com.CompanyName.FirstName_SecondName** in **Android** and **com.CompanyName.FirstName-SecondName** in **iOS**, due to the naming restrictions. Technically, it should not work or should it? I am confused here. What are my best options?

Comment: Why shouldn't be a single key??

Comment: I cannot use the "-" in Android and "_" key in iOS

Comment: Why you need two keys.. at a time you are using single app at a time... right?

Comment: An Android app and an iOS app. I could try to reduce the space from the Bundle ID and the package ID but we need both of them for other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK It will not work this both name will be referred as different packages. So you need to keep the both packages name same. So that it can be registered for same package and fire the push notification to both application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you tell me what are my best options to do that? I cannot remove the "-" and "_" because I have other apps using the without space names.

Comment: I suggest you to use "." instead. Or you can completely remove "-" and "_".

Comment: Alright, let me do that then. Are there any best practices that I am missing to handle these type of scenarios?

Comment: Well need to do research for that. :)